# Tail recursion vs List.fold_left

Tags: ocaml

I can't understand difference between tail recursion and `List.fold_left`?

What is difference? When should I use Tail recursion and when `List.fold_left`?

Comment: Tail recursion is a programming concept, whereas `List.fold_left` is a function that uses it? Your question is quite unclear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.fold_left` is a functional generalization of a iterating over a sequence. It is a function that takes a list, some initial value, and apply this function to each element of a list in order. This is a well known [higher order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) function in functional programming. And it usually used for looping and iteration instead of directly using recursion.

Tail recursion is a particular case of a tail call, when the call is made to the function itself. Basically, a call is tail, if it is the last expression in the function. So that after the call there is no need to perform any more evaluations. Tail call are optimized in OCaml too simple iterations, i.e., they don't consume stack as normal call do.

`List.fold_left` is implemented using recursion, and all recursive calls in the standard implementation are in the tail position. There is also a `List.fold_right` that some times implemented non tail recursively.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is "what can I do using tail recursion that I can't using `fold_left` and vice versa", the answer is:

Anything that can be implemented using `fold_left` can be implemented using tail recursion as `fold_left` itself is commonly implemented using tail recursion. The following things can be implemented using tail recursion, but not `fold_left`:

- Anything where you iterate over something other than a list (say you're iterating until an integer is 0).
- Anything where you iterate over a list, but not one element at a time.
- Anything where you iterate over a list, but you may stop before reaching the end.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Sepp2k's answer, as of OCaml 4.07 the [`Seq`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) module provides a `fold_left` function that works analogously to `List.fold_left`. Leveraging this, we can iterate over things which are not lists but *can* be lazily iterated over.

Notably we can create a sequence of numbers counting down from one number to another, and then fold over that.

```
# let count_down_seq from to_val =
    let rec aux n () =
      if n < to_val then Seq.Nil
      else Seq.Cons (n, aux @@ n - 1)
    in
    aux from;;
val count_down_seq : int -> int -> int Seq.t = <fun>
# count_down_seq 5 1 |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1]
# count_down_seq 5 1 |> Seq.fold_left (+) 0;;
- : int = 15
# count_down_seq 5 1 |> Seq.fold_left (Fun.flip List.cons) [];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```